# python: get image link from html

Tags: python, xml, regex

From a html/rss snippet like this

```
[...]<div class="..." style="..."></div><p><a href="..."
<img alt="" heightt="" src="http://link.to/image"
width="" /></a><span style="">[...]
```

I want to get the image src link "http://link.to/image.jpg". How can I do this in python? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Is it HTML or RSS? That's an important distinction. And the correct answer is to use proper parser, I'm sure Python has those.

Comment: ok for RSS I should use a parser, but what if it's html?

Comment: If it is RSS you should use an RSS parser (possibly followed by an HTML parser one you extract the HTML). For HTML you should use an HTML parser.

Answer (score 6):

[`lxml`](http://lxml.de) is the tool for the job.

To scrape all the images from a webpage would be as simple as this:

```
import lxml.html

tree = lxml.html.parse("http://example.com")
images = tree.xpath("//img/@src")

print images
```

Giving:

`['/_img/iana-logo-pageheader.png', '/_img/icann-logo-micro.png']`

If it was an RSS feed, you'd want to parse it with `lxml.etree`.

Answer (score 2):

Using urllib and beautifulsoup:

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

f = urllib.urlopen(url)
page = f.read()
f.close()          
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
for link in soup.findAll('img'):
    print "IMAGE LINKS:", link.get('data-src')
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should start with reading [Regex Howto](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html) tutorial and a FAQ in the StackOverflow which says that whenever you are dealing with XMLs (HTML) dont use Regex, but rather using good parsers and in your case, [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html) is one.

Using Regex, you would do this to get the link to your image:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'src="(http://.*\.jpg)"')
pattern.search("yourhtmlcontainingtheimagelink").group(1)
```

Comment: Pre-emptive dissuasion from using regex, I like it :)

Comment: What if the image is a png: I would use pattern = re.compile(r'src="(.*?)"')

Comment: Instead of `jpg` you would use `png`. If you do the above, it would give all the src links (.html etc) and not just images.

Comment: @SandyBr - This is why you do not use Regex for parsing HTML. It is a solved problem. Be lazy and use `lxml` (for which I gave the simple snippet that does what you want in my answer below) or BeautifulSoup. [`Read this`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) if you want to know about the horror that is using Regex for parsing HTML.

Answer (score 0):

To add to svick's answer,
try using the [BeautifuSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) parser, it worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

get html tag data, according to [tornado spider](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/demos/webspider/webspider.py#L35)

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

def get_links(html):
    class URLSeeker(HTMLParser):
        def __init__(self):
            HTMLParser.__init__(self)
            self.urls = []

        def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
            if tag == 'img':
                src = dict(attrs).get('src')
                if src:
                    self.urls.append(src)

    url_seeker = URLSeeker()
    url_seeker.feed(html)
    return url_seeker.urls
```