# Python: get CATCHA file from html

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, captcha

I try to decode captcha on python, but I don't know, how can I get it from html.
I use

```
html = session.get(page, headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

And html looks like

```
<img src="/captcha.gif" style="width:1px;height:1px"/>
```

How can I exctract it? I can do it only with save image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python: get image link from html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927031/python-get-image-link-from-html)

Answer (score 0):

you can get image on your PC like this:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

tag = '<img src="/captcha.gif" style="width:1px;height:1px"/>'
soup = BS(tag)
img_tag = soup.find('img')
urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://absolute/path/to'+img_tag['src'], os.getcwd() + '/temp_img')
```

Comment: I have an error `urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)>`. I check is that domain has redirect with `print(session.get(page, headers=headers).url)` and it returns me `https://moskva.tiu.ru/Tehnicheskie-moyuschie-sredstva;50` and get link to image and it looks like `/captcha.gif`, but `urllib.request.urlretrieve(page + img_link, '/Users/elenadevyataykina/PycharmProjects/parsing_contacts/captcha/')` returns error

Comment: I don't know how you get captcha, I made > 150 requests to page `https://moskva.tiu.ru/Tehnicheskie-moyuschie-sredstva` without pausing and didn't catch captcha page. Are you sure, you really need captcha resolving?=)

Comment: what is the value of `page` that you pass in `rllib.request.urlretrieve()`?

Comment: It has blocked me after ~ 3000 requests with interval 3 seconds

Comment: Only with url without img?

Comment: only `page`, img is known, isn't it? `img_link` should be equal to `"/captcha.gif"`

Comment: `urllib.request.urlretrieve(page)` also returns an error

Comment: the VALUE of `page`. Like `page = https://moskva.tiu.ru` or something else

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151511/discussion-between-dmitriy-fialkovskiy-and-petr-petrov).